# SMTPConnectError: (421, b'Server busy, too many connections')

Tags: python, django

I have watched videos and practice the same thing yet I keep getting smtp connect error

```
EMAIL_BACKEND= 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'captainleon04@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ='ppbdhcdnj'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: With the given input, My guess is that you're not closing any live connections.  Kill all your python processes and then close connection, and try again.

Comment: how do I kill my python processes? I do not understand

Comment: If you're using Linux, then `kill -9 <pid>` or if you're using windows, Go to **task manager** and **terminate** any running python processes.

Comment: Now I have killed the python process, do I close the connection by inputting Control + c on windows?

Comment: No, Let me add an example in the answer and you'll understand what I mean by closing connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code and it shows how the connection to the server is closed `server.quit()`.

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login("your username", "your password")
server.sendmail(
  "from@address.com", 
  "to@address.com", 
  "this message is from python")
server.quit()
```

Comment: Ok, so I replace my code with this